# What Windows 10 serial framing protocol uses "CLIENT" as part of its handshake?

Tags: windows, ppp, dial-up

I need to implement IP networking over a bytestream with one end a custom microcontroller and the other end Windows or Linux, I've selected PPP for the protocol, which was straightforward to set up on Linux.

For Windows, I've read Mark Silver's "PPP on Windows 10" and tried to set up a Windows machine accordingly. However, when I attempt to dial the connection ( over a "communications cable between two computers"), I eventually get Error 777 ( the connection attempt failed because the modem is out of order ).

I implemented a simpler serial sniffer on the other end and logged what windows is sending: CLIENT, CLIENT, CLIENT(no newline/carriage return) a few times a second or so apart before throwing the error. The sniffer format is

DirectionIndicator:0xHX|AsciiByte

```
R:0x43|C
R:0x4C|L
R:0x49|I
R:0x45|E
R:0x4E|N
R:0x54|T
R:0x43|C
R:0x4C|L
R:0x49|I
R:0x45|E
R:0x4E|N
R:0x54|T
```

What protocol is this? Is there some way to get Windows 10 into straight PPP mode?

Comment: See if the article [PPP on Windows 10](https://ig8g.com/out/utilities/PPP/PPPWindows10SetupNotes_RevA.pdf) solves the problem.

Comment: It does not. That's the article I was following.